# List of lists middle element extraction in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists as follows

```
[('trojan', 'virus', 0.4731800100841465), ('elb', 'Ebola', 0.3722390506633956)]
```

How to extract only the middle element i.e. 'virus' and 'Ebola' ?

Comment: `print([i[1] for i in [('trojan', 'virus', 0.4731800100841465), ('elb', 'Ebola', 0.3722390506633956)] ])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a comprehnesion list

```
your_list = [('trojan', 'virus', 0.4731800100841465), ('elb', 'Ebola', 0.3722390506633956)]
l = [x[1] for x in your_list]
```

output:

```
['virus', 'Ebola']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find middle index

```
data = [
    ('trojan', 'virus', 0.4731800100841465),
    ('elb', 'Ebola', 0.3722390506633956)
]
middle_data = []
for inside_list in data:
    middle = len(inside_list)/2
    middle_data.append(inside_list[middle])
print(middle_data)
```

## Output: `['virus', 'Ebola']`